# C# - could someone explain different System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() behaviour on Mac OS X vs Windows 10

Tags: c#, multithreading

I built a terminal Snake application in Visual Studio Community 2017 in Mac OS X.

The game uses this code to wait for user input before moving on to render next frame on terminal:

```
public static int[] GetUserInput(int[] currentDirection)
{
    int[] nextMove = currentDirection; // { x , y }

    ConsoleKeyInfo input = new ConsoleKeyInfo();

    int timeElapsed = 0;
    int waitTime = gameSpeed;

    for (int cnt = waitTime; cnt > 0; cnt--)
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            input = Console.ReadKey();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        timeElapsed++;
    }

    // Code that handles input //

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(waitTime-timeElapsed);

    return nextMove;
}
```

Variable `gameSpeed` is time in miliseconds during which player must press a key (i.e. rate at which frames are rendered to console).

Basically, user is given certain amount of time to press a key. If a key is pressed, the GetUserInput() function waits remaining time before rendering next frame. If no key is pressed it waits the `gameSpeed` amount of time before rendering next frame. This way the framerate (i.e. time between frame renderings) of game is kept the same.

When I run this on my old 2011 MacBook Pro the game is perfectly smooth and plays great.

I tried running it on my 2016 Dell Latitude and it doesn't behave even remotely like on my MacBook. The frames render with 1-2 second intervals and if you hold a key down it suddenly starts rendering frames really fast.

This is the only place in the whole application where I use *System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()*, so there couldn't be other pieces of code which cause this behavior.

I read that using *System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()* is a bad practice, but I am just curious if someone could explain why the application behaves so differently on these two devices / operating systems.

I am new to programming so any suggestions / pointers to how this code could be written better would be greatly appreciated

Rest of the code can be found on my GitHub repository: https://github.com/krisjanis-a/Snake

Comment: your program doesn't account for the time it takes to call "KeyAvailable" and for context switching. Those will vary depending on OS and processor and system load, etc.

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` will sleep for at least the time given, but perhaps longer if other processes are running. Need to do a realtime check to determine when to give up and how long to sleep.

Comment: On Windows the minimum granularity for a `Sleep` is the resolution of the system clock -- which, if it hasn't been boosted by other calls, is 15 ms. A call like `Sleep(1)` will at a *minimum* sleep for 15 ms by default, and may sleep for much longer if the scheduler prioritizes other threads. Nor do simple linear variables like `timeElapsed` accurately reflect time; for that something like `Stopwatch` is needed.